# SQL UPDATE from other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on complicated problem, but I will simplify it to this problem.

I have two tables

```
A [ID, column1, column2, column3]
B [ID, column1, column2, column3, column4]
C [ID, column1, column2,column3]
```

I am creating another third table using this query.

```
UPDATE C 
  set column1=t.firstTab, column2=t.secondTab, column3=t.thirdTab 
  from (select A.column1 as firstTab, B.column2 as secTab, 
              (A.column1 + B.column2) thirdTab 
        from A, B limit 1; ) as t ;
```

I got: UPDATE 0

when I run this query:

```
select A.column1 as firstTab, B.column2 as secTab, (A.column1 + B.column2) thirdTab 
            from A, B limit 1;
```

I got results.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, fix the description ("I have two tables" followed by *three* tables and "I am creating a third table" followed by an `update` rather than a `create table` statement).

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to update all rows of C with just the values from the first row of the projection t?

Comment: @StuartLC : Yes, exactly. This is what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments, this will update all rows of C from the first row (unspecified order) of the projection:

```
UPDATE C
  set column1=t.firstTab, column2=t.secTab, column3=t.thirdTab 
  FROM 
    (select A.column1 as firstTab, B.column2 as secTab, 
            (A.column1 + B.column2) thirdTab 
     from A, B limit 1) as t;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e4d08/2)

If you just want to update ONE row of C with the first row of the projection, and if C.ID is a primary key:

```
UPDATE C 
  set column1=t.firstTab, column2=t.secondTab, column3=t.thirdTab 
  from
  (select A.column1 as firstTab, B.column2 as secondTab, 
              (A.column1 + B.column2) thirdTab 
        from A, B limit 1) as t 
  WHERE C.ID IN (SELECT ID from C LIMIT 1);
```

However, if you have no primary key on C, then you can use the [CTID system column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-system-columns.html):

```
UPDATE C 
  set column1=t.firstTab, column2=t.secondTab, column3=t.thirdTab 
  from
  (select A.column1 as firstTab, B.column2 as secondTab, 
              (A.column1 + B.column2) thirdTab 
        from A, B limit 1) as t 
  WHERE CTID IN (SELECT CTID from C LIMIT 1);
```

[Updated Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e4d08/30)

Comment: I am not seeing difference between your query and mine.

Comment: 2 minor things - remove the semicolon after the limit, and the projected column name is `secTab`. The fiddle works. Perhaps your real query is more involved than the example given and doesn't demonstrate the issue?

Comment: But why we are getting duplications ?

Comment: ? Do you just want to update the first row of C with the first row of the projection? Typically you would have some kind of join condition between A, B and C.